# Oracle Notification Dapper

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, dapper, caliburn.micro

I am trying to make use of Oracle's continuous query notification, but in WPF MVVM with Dapper and Caliburn.Micro.

I've set up a static OracleConnector class where dapper is querying db and populates a List like this:

`List<Employees> List = cnn.Query<Employees>(OracleDynamicParameters.sql, param: dyParam).AsList();`

In my View I bound a DataGrid to that list:
`<DataGrid VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"/>`

I have the below event triggered when a row is changed in database:

```
private void OnMyNotificaton(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Result set has changed.", "Notification Alert",
         MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

        // Append ROWID(s) to the base query to retrieve just modified row(s)
        DataRow detailRow = args.Details.Rows[0];
        string rowid = detailRow["Rowid"].ToString();
        string sqlUpdate = sqlSelect + "where rowid = \'" + rowid + "\'";

        // Append on to the sqlUpdate statement if there are additional 
        // updated rows
        for (int i = 1; i < args.Details.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            detailRow = args.Details.Rows[i];
            rowid = detailRow["Rowid"].ToString();
            sqlUpdate = sqlUpdate + " or rowid = \'" + rowid + "\'";
        }

        // Refresh changed data


        using (OracleConnection con2 = new OracleConnection(constr))
        {
            OracleConnector.List.Clear();
            OracleConnector.List = con2.Query<Employees>(sqlUpdate, new DynamicParameters()).AsList();

        }
```

How can I refresh that row in my List and also notify VieModel about the list changes?

As you can see, I am just clearing my list and trying to query again the database with dapper and add the result to the List. The problem is only changed rows are inserted again in the list and also my DataGrid is not updating.

Oracle's example is using an OracleDataAdapter which populates a DataSet and bind it to a DataGrid like so:

```
        // Refresh changed data

        OracleConnection con2 = new OracleConnection(constr); 
        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand(sqlUpdate, con2);
        con2.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter da2 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd2);
        da2.Fill(ds, tablename);
```

How can I achieve this with Dapper?

**EDIT 1**

I've read some tips that ObservableCollection is not notifying about changes on items inside and someone suggested to extend it like this:

```
public class FullyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
     where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property is changed within an item.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs> ItemPropertyChanged;

    public FullyObservableCollection() : base()
    { }

    public FullyObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list)
    {
        ObserveAll();
    }

    public FullyObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) : base(enumerable)
    {
        ObserveAll();
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove ||
            e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= ChildPropertyChanged;
        }

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add ||
            e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
        }

        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected void OnItemPropertyChanged(ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemPropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnItemPropertyChanged(int index, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnItemPropertyChanged(new ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs(index, e));
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (T item in Items)
            item.PropertyChanged -= ChildPropertyChanged;

        base.ClearItems();
    }

    private void ObserveAll()
    {
        foreach (T item in Items)
            item.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        T typedSender = (T)sender;
        int i = Items.IndexOf(typedSender);

        if (i < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Received property notification from item not in collection");

        OnItemPropertyChanged(i, e);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Provides data for the <see cref="FullyObservableCollection{T}.ItemPropertyChanged"/> event.
/// </summary>
public class ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the index in the collection for which the property change has occurred.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Index in parent collection.
    /// </value>
    public int CollectionIndex { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The index in the collection of changed item.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the property that changed.</param>
    public ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs(int index, string name) : base(name)
    {
        CollectionIndex = index;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The index.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The <see cref="PropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    public ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs(int index, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) : this(index, args.PropertyName)
    { }
}
```

When doing this it seems that the event is triggered when items are added/removed/changed but then again, ViewModel is not aware of this changes and View is not updating.

Here is my model class:

```
public class Employees : ObservableObject
{
    private double _salary;
    private int _employeeId;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string email;
    private string phoneNumber;


    public int EMPLOYEE_ID {
        get
        {
            return _employeeId;
        }
        set
        {
            _employeeId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EMPLOYEE_ID");

        }
    }
    public string FIRST_NAME {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FIRST_NAME");
        }
    }
    public string LAST_NAME
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LAST_NAME");
        }
    }
    public string EMAIL
    {
        get
        {
            return email;
        }
        set
        {
            email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EMAIL");
        }
    }
    public string PHONE_NUMBER
    {
        get
        {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            phoneNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
    }
    public double SALARY {
        get
        {
            return _salary;
        }

        set
        {
            _salary = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SALARY");
        }
    }

}
```

and base model class

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (propertyName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
        }

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

The list is populated in OracleConnector.cs

```
public class OracleConnector
{
    public static FullyObservableCollection<Employees> List;

    private static string LoadConnectionString(string id = "HR")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString.ToString();
    }

    public static FullyObservableCollection<Employees> GetEmployeeRepositorys(string connectionString)
    {

         using (IDbConnection cnn = new OracleConnection(LoadConnectionString(connectionString)))
        {
            var dyParam = new OracleDynamicParameters();

            try
            {

                var output = cnn.Query<Employees>(OracleDynamicParameters.sqlSelect, param: dyParam);
                List = new FullyObservableCollection<Employees>(output);


            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection to database is not available.\n" + ex.Message, "Database not available", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            return List;

        }
    }

}
```

and changes to dbs are catched in OracleDynamicParameters class

```
public class OracleDynamicParameters : SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters
{
    private readonly DynamicParameters dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
    private readonly List<OracleParameter> oracleParameters = new List<OracleParameter>();


    public static string tablename = "Employees";
    public static string constr = "User Id=hr;Password=hr;Pooling=false;Data Source=ORCL;";
    public static string sqlSelect = "select employee_id, first_name, " +
                                     "last_name, salary from employees ";
    public static string sql = sqlSelect + "where employee_id < 200";
    public static DataSet ds = new DataSet();


    public void Add(string name, OracleDbType oracleDbType, ParameterDirection direction, object value = null, int? size = null)
    {
        OracleParameter oracleParameter;
        if (size.HasValue)
        {
            oracleParameter = new OracleParameter(name, oracleDbType, size.Value, value, direction);
        }
        else
        {
            oracleParameter = new OracleParameter(name, oracleDbType, value, direction);
        }

        oracleParameters.Add(oracleParameter);
    }

    public void Add(string name, OracleDbType oracleDbType, ParameterDirection direction)
    {
        var oracleParameter = new OracleParameter(name, oracleDbType, direction);
        oracleParameters.Add(oracleParameter);
    }

    public void AddParameters(IDbCommand command, SqlMapper.Identity identity)
    {
        ((SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters)dynamicParameters).AddParameters(command, identity);

        if (command is OracleCommand oracleCommand)
        {
            oracleCommand.AddRowid = true;

            OracleDependency dep = new OracleDependency(oracleCommand);

            oracleCommand.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
            dep.OnChange += Dep_OnChange;
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand)
            {
                MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
            };

            oracleCommand.Parameters.AddRange(oracleParameters.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private void Dep_OnChange(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Result set has changed.", "Notification Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

        // Append ROWID(s) to the base query to retrieve just modified row(s)
        DataRow detailRow = args.Details.Rows[0];
        string rowid = detailRow["Rowid"].ToString();
        string sqlUpdate = sqlSelect + "where rowid = \'" + rowid + "\'";

        // Append on to the sqlUpdate statement if there are additional 
        // updated rows
        for (int i = 1; i < args.Details.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            detailRow = args.Details.Rows[i];
            rowid = detailRow["Rowid"].ToString();
            sqlUpdate = sqlUpdate + " or rowid = \'" + rowid + "\'";
        }

        // Refresh changed data

        OracleConnection con2 = new OracleConnection(constr);
        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand(sqlUpdate, con2);
        con2.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter da2 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd2);
        da2.Fill(ds, tablename);
        OracleConnector.List.Clear();

        OracleConnector.List = new FullyObservableCollection<Employees>(ds.Tables["Employees"].AsEnumerable().Select(p => new Employees
        {
            EMPLOYEE_ID = p.Field<int>("EMPLOYEE_ID"),
            FIRST_NAME = p.Field<string>("FIRST_NAME"),
            LAST_NAME = p.Field<string>("LAST_NAME")
        }));
    }
}
```

and finally ShellViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private FullyObservableCollection<Employees> _employees;
    private Employees _selectedEmployee;

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public Employees SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            _selectedEmployee = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedEmployee);
        }
    }

    public FullyObservableCollection<Employees> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set
        {
            _employees = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Employees);


        }
    }

    #region Constructor

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        _employees = new FullyObservableCollection<Employees>(OracleConnector.GetEmployeeRepositorys("HR"));

    }

    #endregion

}
```

What am I doing wrong because I really cannot see where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The employee list needs to be an observable list ie that tells a potential listener ie the view model binding, when it has been modified. A plain list does not do that. Change the `Employees` list to an `ObservableCollection<Employee>`. In due course you are almost certain to need to implement the `IChangeNotification` in your `Employee` class as well when properties are changed.

Comment: Sadly, I did that already but without success, I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for every property in Employee model class, changed to a ObservableCollection<Employees> but is not updating the view even if i add/delete an item on the collection or if I am changing one.

Is there specific I should do in the ViewModel?